# Excel macro CSV issue

Tags: excel, csv, gmail, vba

Im using a excel macro which generates a csv file with all my data to upload to gmail as contacts. When the file is uploaded to gmail contacts, the mobile number and the work number come correctly but the persons name comes in the notes box as "First Name: Yash".
Im attaching a sample csv file which is generated by the macro.

[Download Sample CSV HERE](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-GFlDCTgJv5X1NaYmdpVjE3OTg/view?usp=sharing)

im using the following macro to generate the csv's:

```
Sub getcsv()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
csvnewsheet
Dim myRange As Range
Dim NumRows As Integer
Set myRange = ActiveSheet.Range("A:A")
NumRows = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(myRange)
    Range("E1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "First Name"
    Range("E2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=CONCATENATE(Reports!R[5]C2,"" "",Reports!R[5]C1)"
    Range("E2").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("E2:E" & NumRows + 1)
    Range("E2:E3").Select
    Columns("E:E").EntireColumn.AutoFit
    hide_format
    Exporttocsv
    DelSht
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub


Sub hide_format()
'
' hides name & place columns and then removed the formatting
'

'
    Columns("A:A").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Columns("C:C").Select
    Selection.Cut
    Columns("A:A").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight
    Range("A1").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlEdgeLeft).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlEdgeTop).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlEdgeRight).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlInsideVertical).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlInsideHorizontal).LineStyle = xlNone
    With Selection.Interior
       .Pattern = xlNone
       .TintAndShade = 0
       .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
End Sub



   Sub csvnewsheet()
    Dim myRange As Range
    Dim NumRows As Integer
    Set myRange = Worksheets("Reports").Range("A:A")
    NumRows = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(myRange) + 3
    Sheets.Add.Name = Worksheets("Reports").Range("A2").Value & "_CSV"
    Worksheets("Reports").Range("A6:D" & NumRows).Copy Destination:=Worksheets(Worksheets("Reports").Range("A2").Value & "_CSV").Range("A1")
    Worksheets(Worksheets("Reports").Range("A2").Value & "_CSV").Columns("A:D").AutoFit
    End Sub



    Sub Exporttocsv()
    Dim MyPath As String
    Dim MyFileName As String

    MyFileName = Worksheets("Reports").Range("A2").Value & "_CSV"
    If Not Right(MyFileName, 4) = ".csv" Then MyFileName = MyFileName & ".csv"

    Worksheets(Worksheets("Reports").Range("A2").Value & "_CSV").Copy

    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
        .Title = "Select a Folder to Save the CSV"
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .InitialFileName = "" '<~~ The start folder path for the file picker.
        If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
        MyPath = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
    End With

    NextCode:

    With ActiveWorkbook
        .saveas Filename:=MyPath & MyFileName, FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
        .Close False
    End With
    End Sub


    Sub DelSht()
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        Sheets(Worksheets("Reports").Range("A2").Value & "_CSV").Delete
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    End Sub
```

This macro generates a new sheet with the data then will do the required changes and save as CSV and then delete that sheet.

i dont know where im going wrong...but the contact names just dont come in gmail... ive tried various other methods but it still didnt work...

Please help!

Comment: I can't see in the code you provided where you are looking for contact names from Gmail.

Comment: @Davesexcel This code generates a CSV file which is to be uploaded on gmail. When this file uploads on gmail, the contact name appears in the Notes box instead of the Name box.

Comment: I download your example, run the code and nothing shows up in the CSV file. It's just blank.

Comment: The sample file is the final generated CSV file. I'm using a macro on another workbook with data to generate this CSV file. Upload this file on gmail contacts and see.

Answer (score 1):

***This is how Gmail suggests the format of the csv file.***

-

[image: Gmail CSV]

this is how you have yours formatted.

[image]

You may have to have it formatted the way Gmail suggests.

Comment: How about copying Gmail example, and see if that works?